# 503 Service Unavailable при большем массиве PHP

Tags: php, php.ini

проблема в следующем. При генерации массива в цикле while получаю ошибку 503, в массив записывается около 100 000 строк.
Параметры:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

но ошибка не исчезает.
Если цикл ограничить в 50 000 строк то все ОК.
Какие параметры менять чтобы исправить данную ошибку?
Ах да, массив записывается в БД

Comment: Смотрите лог ошибок. Может он прольёт свет на вашу проблему. Пробуйте увеличить время выполнения `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1300);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно правильно подходить к вопросу. 
Скорее всего проблема с выделением памяти не смотря на то что у вас потенциально в продакшене параметр -1 . Однако исползуя генераторы у вас этих проблем не будет. Аляулю.
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php

А вот дочитал вопрос. В лучших домах Лондона и Парижа обычно выкладывают тот код, которые генерит ошибку.  Не исключено что БД огорчает. Вопрос ведь в том - через ORM вы работаете или PDO используете...

Comment: Я использую PDO

Comment: public function get_product($url){
$data_product = [];
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($url); 
while($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'offer');
while($xml->name === 'offer'){
$node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());$data_product[] = [
"id"          => $xml->getAttribute("id"),
"available"   => $xml->getAttribute("available"),
"price"       => $node->price,
"name"        => $node->name, 
"description" => $node->description,
];
$xml->next('offer');
}
$xml->close(); 
return $data_product; 
}

Comment: Это метод парсера

Comment: Даже если не делать запросов в БД то все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @АлександрЕна так это, ответ то вы читали ? То что в первом абзаце ?

Comment: Я не знаю как мне использовать генератор в моем цикле =(

Comment: while($xml->read() &&  $xml->name !== 'offer');                                    
while($xml->name === 'offer'){

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! Вы меня направили на верный путь

Answer (score 0):

> Какие параметры менять чтобы исправить данную ошибку?

вот этот

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Причем тут вывод ошибок?